# Elasticsearch query retrieve fetch expecting result in top 25 results

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have 200K records and trying to fetch records based on certain match criteria 
ex: company_name: "test" 
If i give size:250 expecting record is not available in search results.
size:500 the expecting document is fetched and displayed. 
How to get the document in top 25 results ?

Query : {"explain":true,"size":250,"query":{"query_string":{"query":" ( (NAME:\"BANK AMERICA\")^50 OR (ceoNames.fullCEOName:(BANK AMERICA))^30  OR  (NAME_PAIR:\"BANK AMERICA\")^30   OR (NORMAL_NAME:(BANK AMERICA) AND CITY:\"\" ) ^40 OR (NORMAL_NAME:(BANK AMERICA))^30  OR (tradeStyles.acronym:\"BS\")^5 OR (NORMAL_NAME_SOUNDEX:\"BANK AMERICA\")^5   OR (address.streetName:\"\" AND CITY:\"\")^30 OR (ZIP:\"\")^6 OR (address.streetName:\"\")^6  OR (address.streetNumber:\"\" AND address.streetName:\"\")^15 OR (telephones.telephone:\"\")^50 OR (mailAddresses.postbox:\"\")^6  ) "}},"sort":[{"_score":{"order":"desc"}},{"statusIndicator":{"order":"asc"}}],"aggs":{"NAME":{"filter":{"term":{"NAME":"ATLS"}}}}}

Comment: Please show us the query that you're using exactly.

Comment: @ Ryan Bigg please find the query updated in the post.